# Lightweight 3D animation driven by external data

Tags: animation, 3d

I'm a structural engineering master student work on a seismic evaluation of a temple structure in Portugal. For the evaluation, I have created a 3D block model of the structure and will use a discrete element code to analyze the behaviour of the structure under a variety of seismic (earthquake) records. The software that I will use for the analysis has the ability to produce snapshots of the structure at regular intervals which can then be put together to make a movie of the response. However, producing the images slows down the analysis. Furthermore, since the pictures are 2D images from a specified angle, there is no possibility to rotate and view the response from other angles without re-running the model (a process that currently takes 3 days of computer time).

I am looking for an alternative method for creating a movie of the response of the structure. What I want is a very lightweight solution, where I can just bring in the block model which I have and then produce the animation by feeding in the location and the three principal axis of each block at regular intervals to produce the animation on the fly. The blocks are described as prisms with the top and bottom planes defining all of the vertices. Since the model is produced as text files, I can modify the output so that it can be read and understood by the animation code. The model is composed of about 180 blocks with 24 vertices per block (so 4320 vertices). The location and three unit vectors describing the block axis are produced by the program and I can write them out in a way that I want.

The main issue is that the quality of the animation should be decent. If the system is vector based and allows for scaling, that would be great. I would like to be able to rotate the model in real time with simple mouse dragging without too much lag or other issues.

I have very limited time (in fact I am already very behind). That is why I wanted to ask the experts here so that I don't waste my time on something that will not work in the end. I have been using Rhino and Grasshopper to generate my model but I don't think it is the right tool for this purpose. I was thinking that Processing might be able to handle this but I don't have any experience with it. Another thing that I would like to be able to do is to maybe have a 3D PDF file for distribution. But I'm not sure if this can be done with 3D PDF.

Any insight or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you have a lot of 2D Images at different angles, have you considered an [**Image 3D Rotator Plugin**](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/jquery-360-degrees-image-display-plugins/#.T-JMfJFsPTc)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't let the name fool you, but [**BluffTitler DX9**](http://www.outerspace-software.com/blufftitler.html), a commercial software, may be what your looking for.

It's simple interface provides a fast learning curve, may quick tutorials to either watch or dissect. Depending on how fast your GPU is, real-time previews are scalable.

**Reference:**
[**Model Layer Page**](http://www.outerspace-software.com/modellayer.html)

[**User Submitted Gallery (3D models)**](http://www.outerspace-software.com/gallery/imagebrowser.php?F=32)

Answer (score 0):

Jim Merry from tetra4D here. We make the 3D CAD conversion tools for Acrobat X to generate 3D PDFs. Acrobat has a 3D javascript API that enables you to manipulate objects, i.e, you could drive translations, rotations, etc of objects from your animation information after translating your model to 3D PDF. Not sure I would recommend this approach if you are in a hurry however. Also - I don't think there are any commercial 3D PDF generation tools for the formats you are using (Rhino, Grasshopper, Processing).

If you are trying to animate geometric deformations, 3D PDF won't really help you at all. You could capture the animation and encode it as flash video and embed in a PDF, but this a function of the multimedia tool in Acrobat Pro, i.e, is not specific to 3D.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I was looking at this solution. My blocks are not deformable so I don't need to do vertex level manipulation (which I guess is not supported by 3D Javascript API). All I need is to translate and rotate them. However, I think 3D PDF is not meant for this type of work. Even if it is, I think there is not enough information for someone as inexperienced as me to figure it out in a short amount of time. However, I think this would be a great tool to have since it doesn't require massive amount of data to be stored in the file. Just some transformations.